# Monitoring AWS CodeBuild With CloudWatch Alarms in the CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

**Info:** The AWS Console offers CloudWatch metrics for CodeBuild, such as `FailedBuilds, Duration, InstallDuration, FinalizingDuration`... There are roughly 40 metric options.

**Problem:** When creating with the `pipelines` [in the CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html), I cannot find the equivalent monitoring solution for the `CodeBuildStep` ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html)).

Typically, for example, the `NodejsFunction` has [metric props](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#metricmetricname-props) which I can use to create `AlarmProps` and thus monitor.

**CDK Pipeline Code:**

```js
    this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
      pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
      selfMutation: true,
      crossAccountKeys: false,
      role: this.codePipelineRole,
      cliVersion: "21.0.0",
      synth: new CodeBuildStep("Deployment", {
        input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment),
        env: {environment},
        installCommands: ["npm uninstall -g aws-cdk", "npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g aws-cdk"],
        commands: [
          "cd backend",
          "npm ci",
          "npm run build",
          "npx cdk synth",
        ],
        primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
        buildEnvironment: {
          computeType: ComputeType.SMALL,
        },
      })
    });
```

**Desired Alarm Props:**

```js
    const codeBuildPostBuildDuration = (codeBuild: CodeBuildStep): AlarmProps => ({
        alarmName: "codeBuildPostBuildDuration",
        comparisonOperator: ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_THRESHOLD,
        threshold: 1,
        evaluationPeriods: 1,
        metric: codeBuild.FailedBuilds()
    });
```

What can I do to monitor and create alarms for my CDK CI/CD Pipeline?